# Android - Html edittext

Tags: android, html

I was wondering if there is a way to get the html markup.

For example:

```
finalString = " <font color='#2caeac'>@test</font>";
 editetext.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalString));
```

Now if I want to edit my edittext like this:

```
new_string = edittext.getText().toString(); // getting my "@test"`
new_string = new_string+"<font color='red'>newString</font>";
edittext.settext(Html.fromHtml(new_string));
```

Then my new_string doesn't catch the color of "finalString".

How is it possible to get the color of finalString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to a little tricky solution that involves the replace of tags in an HTML text.
The explanation is in code's comments.

```
String finalString = "<font color='#2caeac'>@test</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalString));

// get the text with html
String new_string = Html.toHtml(textView.getText());
// the result will be something like <p dir="something">text_with_html_here</p>
// get the layout direction (above api 17 you can't use getDirection())
final int direction = Character.getDirectionality(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName().charAt(0));
// check if it's RTL
boolean isRTL = direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT || direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
String layoutDirection = isRTL ? "rtl" : "ltr";
// replace raw tags added with toHtml()
new_string = new_string.replace("<p dir=\"" + layoutDirection + "\">", "").replace("</p>", "");
// use the String
new_string = new_string + "<font color='red'>newString</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(new_string));
```